# Получить список вебкамер на устройстве

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, opencv, wmi, web-camera

Пожалуйста подскажите как можно используя win32api/WMI получить список вебкамер на устройстве ?

Использовать библиотеки для работы с вебкамерами (вроде OpenCV) не имеет смысла так как необходимо только название вебкамеры, для последующего поиска некоторых значений в реестре по этому имени, и их изменению.

Comment: камеры можно найти прямо в реестре

Comment: по названию - да, но ситуация в том, что название камеры не известно

Comment: По классу. Там ууид свой

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить только о WinAPI, скорее всего лучше обратиться к SetupAPI, конкретно - классу *Image*, GUID которого *6bdd1fc6-810f-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f*. Однако стоит иметь в виду, что если в системе имеются цифровые камеры или сканеры, они также попадут в вывод примера ниже.

```
from ctypes import (
   Structure, byref, create_unicode_buffer, c_ubyte, c_ulong,
   c_ushort, c_void_p, c_wchar_p, sizeof, windll
)

class GUID(Structure):
   _fields_ = [
      ('Data1', c_ulong),
      ('Data2', c_ushort),
      ('Data3', c_ushort),
      ('Data4', c_ubyte * 8),
   ]
   def __init__(self, guid):
      lst = guid.split('-')
      fst, lst = lst[0:3], ''.join(lst[3:5])
      fst = [int('0x' + fst[i], 16) for i in range(len(fst))]
      lst = [int('0x' + lst[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)]
      self.Data1 = c_ulong(fst[0])
      self.Data2 = c_ushort(fst[1])
      self.Data3 = c_ushort(fst[2])
      self.Data4 = (c_ubyte * len(lst))(*lst)


class SP_DEVINFO_DATA(Structure):
   _fields_ = [
      ('cbSize',    c_ulong),
      ('GuidClass', GUID),
      ('DevInst',   c_ulong),
      ('Reserved',  c_void_p),
   ]
   def __init__(self):
      self.cbSize = sizeof(self)


class Devices(object):
   def __init__(self, guid = bytes()):
      self.ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 259
      self.__hndl = -1

      if type(guid) is GUID:
         self.__hndl = windll.setupapi.SetupDiGetClassDevsW(
            byref(guid), None, None, 0x2 # DIGCF_PRESENT
         )
      else:
         self.__hndl = windll.setupapi.SetupDiGetClassDevsW(
            guid, None, None, 0x02 | 0x4 # DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES
         )
      if self.__hndl == -1: # INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
         raise OSError(self.__win32error())
   def __win32error(self):
      msg = c_void_p()
      windll.kernel32.FormatMessageW(
         0x00001100, None, windll.kernel32.GetLastError(),
         1024, byref(msg), 0, None
      )
      err = c_wchar_p(msg.value).value
      windll.kernel32.LocalFree(msg)
      return err.strip() if err else 'Что-то пошло не так.'
   def walk(self, args = 0):
      lst, err, i = [], 0, 0
      while err != self.ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS:
         sdd = SP_DEVINFO_DATA()

         ret = windll.setupapi.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(self.__hndl, i, byref(sdd))
         err = windll.kernel32.GetLastError()

         if ret:
            buf, reg, rsz = create_unicode_buffer(4096), c_ulong(), c_ulong()
            if windll.setupapi.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW(
               self.__hndl, byref(sdd), args, byref(reg), buf, len(buf), byref(rsz)
            ): lst.append(buf.value)
         i += 1
      return tuple(lst)
   def __del__(self):
      if self.__hndl:
         if not windll.setupapi.SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(self.__hndl):
            raise OSError(self.__win32error())
   def __enter__(self):
      return self
   def __exit__(self, e_type, e_value, e_trace):
      del self

if __name__ == '__main__':
   with Devices(GUID('6bdd1fc6-810f-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f')) as dev:
      for i in dev.walk():
          print(i)
```

Comment: Честно говоря, я уже разочаровался в попытках сделать это, позже попробую, спасибо.

Comment: [![Камера в диспетчере](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw1in.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw1in.png)
Не сработало, хотя камера подключена и определяется диспетчером устройств.

Comment: @rootkit.sys, не могу сказать однозначно в чем может быть причина, могу однако посоветовать посмотреть на GUID типа шины устройства и по нему ориентироваться. Вполне возможно, что в вашем случа было бы правильнее использовать *ca3e7ab9-b4c3-4ae6-8251-579ef933890f* вместо *6bdd1fc6-810f-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f*, в смысле класс _Camera_, а не _Image_.